# -1 * int.MinValue gives an error

Tags: c#, .net, int

When I write this code

```
Console.WriteLine(-1 * int.MinValue);
```

or

```
int a = -1 * -2147483648;
```

I get an error

> The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode.

Is there compile time check especially for this value?
or is it counting all written expressions real time?

Comment: `int.MinValue` isn't `-21474048`, it's `-2147483648`

Comment: @BoltClock from memory, is that?

Comment: i made a mistake, but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is able to perform the (multiplication) calculation at compile time rather than runtime, so it does.

Since `-1 * int.MinValue` (-1 * -2,147,483,648, thus 2,147,483,648) is greater than `int.MaxValue` (2,147,483,647) it gives you your compile error.

To prove that it isn't special casing your exact statement, try:

```
Console.WriteLine(-2 * 1073741826);
```

and you will get the same behaviour.

Comment: is it counting all written expressions real time?

Comment: If by 'counting' you mean 'calculating', and if by 'real time' you mean 'at compile time' - then (by my understanding) yes.

Comment: @Artur Keyan: Whichever expressions can always be evaluated to constant results (i.e. using constant literal values). If you multiply by a number variable like `-1 * someVar` it won't optimize that.

Answer (score 3):

The Int (or rather Int32) can hold any 32 bit integer value. It ranges from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

-1 * -2147483648 = 2147483648. And that is greater than the max Int32 value. That is the reason you get an overflow.

If you want to do the calculation you can cast one of the values to an Int64. So this should work:

```
(Int64)(-1)*int.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for this to be a special check - the value naturally overflows. It's just like:

```
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue + 1);
```

That clearly overflows `int` - and it's the same value as `int.MinValue * -1`.

From section 7.19 of the C# 4 spec:

> Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an unchecked context, overflows that occur in integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions during the compile-time evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are run time checks for values. int values are from -21474048 to +21474047 (why? [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). So you get an exception.